# Font smoothing in Delphi

Tags: delphi, fonts, truetype, smoothing

I had cause to need a label with a large font on a Delphi form and noticed that 
its curves were still slightly jagged. I compared this with the same size 
and font in MSWord which was much smoother. After research I found code 
that allowed me to smooth my fonts but it's messy and I was wondering if 
there was a better way? Looking in the VCL source, TFont seems wedded to 
NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY which is rather frustrating...

Thanks Bri

```
procedure TForm1.SetFontSmoothing(AFont: TFont);
var
  tagLOGFONT: TLogFont;
begin
  GetObject(
    AFont.Handle,
    SizeOf(TLogFont),
    @tagLOGFONT);
  tagLOGFONT.lfQuality  := ANTIALIASED_QUALITY;
  AFont.Handle := CreateFontIndirect(tagLOGFONT);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I : integer;
begin
  For I :=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
    If Components[I] is TLabel then
      SetFontSmoothing( TLabel( Components[I] ).Font );
end;
```

Comment: So does this code work (and you just want to clean it and find some easy way) or is it still not smooth enough or doesn't work?

Comment: Which part of this code do you consider messy?

Comment: It seems wasteful that I've got to poke every font on every label when the VCL has already done this. I looked for something I could override or subclass but with no luck. I guess this is the only way of achieving what I want. Bri

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can trick the VCL into creating your own class that inherits from `TLabel`. *This is proof-of-concept code, tested with Delphi 4, which should get you started.*

Create a new unit for your own `TLabel` class:

```
unit AntiAliasedLabel;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Controls, StdCtrls, Graphics;

type
  TLabel = class(StdCtrls.TLabel)
  private
    fFontChanged: boolean;
  public
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TLabel.Paint;
var
  LF: TLogFont;
begin
  if not fFontChanged then begin
    Win32Check(GetObject(Font.Handle, SizeOf(TLogFont), @LF) <> 0);
    LF.lfQuality := ANTIALIASED_QUALITY;
    Font.Handle := CreateFontIndirect(LF);
    fFontChanged := TRUE;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Now modify your form unit that contains the label, adding the `AntiAliasedLabel` unit **after** `StdCtrls`. This results in your own class `AntiAliasedLabel.TLabel` being created where normally `StdCtrls.TLabel` would be created.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, the VCL should be checking the System default font smoothing and applying that as the default at run-time.   If not, at least it should default to a more reasonable smoothing.  One could argue, in this case, that ClearType would be a better default, considering > 50% of monitors these days are LCD (and greater than 50% of machines are running XP or better).

This is an acknowledged hack (and as Ken White mentions, not the best approach if there are alternatives), but I needed a way to fix this globally for forms containing literally hundreds of 3rd-party component types (making component inheritance unrealistic).

I changed the default Font Quality in Graphics.pas, TFont.GetHandle as follows:

// lfQuality := DEFAULT_QUALITY;

lfQuality := 5; // ***(HACK)*** CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, forces cleartype

Answer (score 5):

From: http://objectmix.com/delphi/725245-tlabel-antialiasing-possibile-3.html

"simply using a font that supports font smoothing should fix this. Delphi
uses (or at least used to use) MS Sans Serif as default, which does not
support smoothing (ClearType or otherwise). if you set your font to
Tahoma (best for XP) or Segoe UI (best for Vista), you will
automatically get font smoothing according to system settings in your
Delphi app."

Confirmed, it works beautifully using Delphi XE and Win7. Busy changing all my fonts right now ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create your own component based on TLabel, such as TSmoothLabel or TAntiAliasedLabel, and add your smoothing code to it. Then you use your component instead of the standard TLabel.

Comment: True, but I'm loading an existing DFM that specifies the TLabel class, so your suggestion could work if there is a way of re-registering TLAbel.
Bri

Comment: There is a way but it requires replacing the TLabel.NewInstance VMT entry by an own method at runtime. The JCL (JEDI Code Library) has functions to do this.

Comment: @Brian: Why can't you just fix the DFM and PAS files (from outside the IDE) to use your new class? Alternative: If you're using a version of Delphi that supports them, you could use a class helper for TLabel. (Specify which Delphi in the future.) I don't recommend the class helper route if there's any other way, though, because it will affect any TLabel that's in it's scope.

Comment: @Andreas: This is the wrong approach. That affects every single TLabel everywhere, and relies on things being in the same place in future versions of the VCL. NEVER do things that are hacks when there are other ways of doing them that aren't.