# Using ClearType in Graphics32 library (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, cleartype, graphics32

I'm using [Graphics32](http://www.graphics32.org/wiki/) library in Delphi 2009. Is it possible to render a font using TBitmap32.TextOut method with MS' ClearType technology? I'm aware about GR32's built-in antialiasing (TBitmap32.RenderText) but the overall quality and performance is not gratifying.

[ Update ]

I've encountered another problem - I'm using [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921249/font-smoothing-in-delphi) from Tondrej's link posted in comments in a TCustomImage32 descendant class' method. An instance of that class is working in a dmBlend mode, and I have problem using it's Font.Color property - the text rendered by using TextOut method is ignoring that property (it renders the text as if it has color value "alpha"). The problem didn't occure when using RenderText. Apparently things are ok when painting a TPaintBox32 component.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921249/font-smoothing-in-delphi

Comment: You say you're using "this function"; what function are you talking about? If Tondrej's comment answered your question, then you should move to close this one as no longer relevant. Then post a new question that doesn't assume everyone knows what you're talking about. Or just edit this question to start over, since you don't have any answers anyway.

Comment: I edited the question to be more precise. Sorry for the commotion - it had been posted in a hurry.

Comment: Rob's comment still applies.  You should start a new question.